# Merging the two leftmost column at the end of a Table

Tags: tables, multicolumn

A frustrated `\LaTeX` user here. I want to merge the end of my table so the "terrain correction uncertainty" get merged with cell below the "No." column.

[image: Wrong table where I want to merge the "terrain correction uncertainty" cell with the one below "1"]

What I want:

[image: What I want to do with the table]

What I have done is this:

```
\begin{table} [!htb]
    \caption{Summary of uncertainties in the AVF Bouguer anomaly data}
    \medskip
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{| m{23pt} | m{180pt}| m{180pt} |}
        \hline
        \rowcolor{black!30}
        \rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} \Centering \bfseries No.
        & \Centering \bfseries Source of Uncertainty & \Centering \bfseries Estimated Uncertainty (mGal)\\
        \hline
        \rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex}
        \Centering 1 & \makecell[l]{ Latitude correction \\ (horizontal positioning)} &\Centering $\pm0.05$ mGal \\
        \hline
        \rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Terrain correction uncertainty} &\Centering $\pm0.03$ mGal \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{Tab:AVFUncertTable}
\end{table}
```

the `\multicolumn` at the end gives out "Misplaced `\omit. ...umn{2}{c}{Terrain correction uncertainty}`" error. All example that I read in StackExchange all give header merging. I need footer merging.

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! User `\multicolumn[2}[|r|}{…}`.

Comment: delete the rules as they are not allowed at that point. After _any_ error the pdf is not intended to be usable so it is not surprising if the pdf output is not as you want. (If the intention is to give more height to the rows, set `\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}` before the tabular. Or if you want the rules put them inside not before the multicolumn.

Comment: please have a look if the answer suits the requirement --`\hline` not required in the header since the `\rowcolor` sets it apart -- the correct way to bold the headers is with `\thead` --`\multicolumn` is now right aligned -- to get centering in the headers simply add `\centering` in the definition of  `\thead` in the preamble of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is solved by @Bernard comment, but in writting of your table use of the `tabularray` package can be quite handy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table} [!htb]
    \caption{Summary of uncertainties in the AVF Bouguer anomaly data}
    \label{Tab:AVFUncertTable}
\centering
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec = {c X[l,m] X[c,m] },
                 rowsep=5pt,
                 row{1} = {font=\bfseries, bg=gray!50}
                }
No. & \SetCell[c=1]{c} Source of Uncertainty 
            & \SetCell[c=1]{c} Estimated Uncertainty (mGal) \\
1   & {Latitude correction \\ (horizontal positioning)} 
            & \qty{\pm0.05}{mGal}       \\
\SetCell[c=2]{r}    Terrain correction uncertainty
    &       & \qty{\pm0.03}{mGal}       \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Syntax of writing `tabularray` table is different than at standard tables. For details see package documentation.

- `\SetCell[c=2]{r}` is equivalent to `\multicolumn{2}{r} ...` command at standard tables
- `\row{1} = {font=\bfseries, bg=gray!50}` define font in the first row and background color

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table} [!htb]
        \caption{Summary of uncertainties in the AVF Bouguer anomaly data}
        \medskip
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{m{23pt} m{180pt} m{180pt}}

            \rowcolor{black!30}

            \thead{No.}
                &  \thead{Source of Uncertainty} 
                    & \thead{Estimated Uncertainty (mGal)}\\    

            1 & \makecell[l]{ Latitude correction \\ (horizontal positioning)} & $\pm0.05$ mGal \\
            \hline

            \multicolumn{2}{r}{Terrain correction uncertainty} &$\pm0.03$ mGal \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \label{Tab:AVFUncertTable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (with a advantage: the rules *won't* seem to disappear near the gray cells in some PDF readers at some levels of zoom).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} [!htb]
\caption{Summary of uncertainties in the AVF Bouguer anomaly data}
\medskip
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{wc{23pt}m{180pt}wc{180pt}}%
  [hvlines,colortbl-like,cell-space-limits=3pt]
\rowcolor{black!30}
\bfseries No. & \centering \bfseries Source of Uncertainty &  \bfseries Estimated Uncertainty (mGal)\\
1 & \Block[l]{}{ Latitude correction \\ (horizontal positioning)} & $\pm0.05$ mGal \\
\Block[r]{1-2}{Terrain correction uncertainty} & & $\pm0.03$ mGal \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\label{Tab:AVFUncertTable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thanks man, I have upvoted this answer though it will not show because I lack reputation 